# Call Variable from Constructor of Another Class

Tags: javascript, class, variables, call, aurelia

Say I have a .js file where the class is exported and the constructor is built like this:

```
 constructor(info) {

    this.info = info;
}
```

And on another .js file, I want to call that variable and change it, and I want the changes to be reflected in the original .js file the variable comes from, so I import the class well and inject it:

```
@inject(ContactGateway, Router, TestElement)
export class LoginNormal {
  constructor(contactGateway, router, testelement) {
    this.contactGateway = contactGateway;
    this.router = router;
    this.testelement = testelement;
  }
```

And then on this same .js file, inside a function, I change the original variable:

```
  TestInfo() {
    let testinfo = this.testelement;
    testinfo.info= true;
  }
```

Upon further testing, I see that the original variable isn't being changed at all, what am I doing wrong while trying to change the original variable's boolean through a function in another file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried updating it directly instead of making a `let testinfo` first? `this.testelement.info = true`

Comment: Many pieces miss in you code. The most critical one is where `logininfocustomelement` is defined ?

Comment: @JessedeBruijne same result, it's intersting because I can get the correct state of the variable with the console.log but I can't set it.

Comment: @MotiKorets that's meant to be testelement, my bad, just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably just getting a different instance of `TestElement` injected. Custom Elements are usually scoped to a specific child container or view (depending on the context).

If you want to ensure you get the same instance everywhere, and you're sure you'll only ever need one instance, you could manually register that custom element's class as a singleton on the root container.

It's better though to simply have a separate service / state class where you keep that `info` property. Register that state class as a singleton / instance on the root container, and inject it in both your `TestElement` and `LoginNormal` classes. That's the recommended way to pass information around for reading/modifying between different html resources.

Something like this should typically do the trick (split/move/rename accordingly):

```
@inject(ApplicationState)
export class TestElement {
    constructor(state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}

@inject(ContactGateway, Router, ApplicationState)
export class LoginNormal {
    constructor(contactGateway, router, state) {
        this.contactGateway = contactGateway;
        this.router = router;
        this.state = state;
    }

    TestInfo() {
        this.state.info = true; // will be changed in your TestElement too
    }
}

// the hard way
export class ApplicationState {
    constructor(info) {
        this.info = info;
    }
}

export function configure(config) {
    config.instance(ApplicationState, new ApplicationState(false))
}

// or the easy way (no configure required, but needs parameterless constructor)
@singleton()
export class ApplicationState {
    constructor() {
        this.info = false;
    }
}
```